# JS algoríthm for styling li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey I have a long list of with li-elements. They are styled in squares in a size of 50x50.

Now my question: These li-Tags are for school classes. Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>5a</li>
  <li>5b</li>
  <li>5c</li>
  <li>5d</li>
  <li>6a</li>
  <li>6b</li>
  <li>6c</li>
  <li>6d</li>
</ul>
```

This goes from 5 to 10. And I need a script that gives a specific background for the li-element, according to which number is the first char. And I am ubable to script this.

Comment: *'Now my question'* - I don't see a question

Comment: Alas, we will not write your code for you. Please consult the documentation or a beginner tutorial and try coming up with something that you can post in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First; it's not much of a question as other pointed out.

But here is what you are looking for, using jquery:

```
$("li").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html();
    var number = parseInt(text, 10);
    switch(number){
        case 5:
            $(this).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
            break;
        case 6:
            $(this).css( "backgroundColor", "green" );
            break;            
    }    
});
```

Link to JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JQ25Z/